# Press all class button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im having fun building a little chrome plugin at the moment, but I am stuck at this very annoying error where I cant seem to invoke a click on some buttons on the website I am on. I have been trying around 20 solutions with no success...

The weird thing is that the button does NOT have any Id's they are all the same class and I was wondering how I could click them all at once. IF anyone has a small clue I would be very appreciative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what code you currently have.

Comment: Look at `document.createEvent` and `node.dispatchEvent`

Comment: You want to be able to click all your buttons at the same time? that doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var buttons = document.getElementByClassName("classNameHere");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].click();
}
```